# Efficiently Querying Phrases in a Huge Document Collection

Tags: algorithm, search, text

In an interview, I have received a question that asks me to **design a search engine for an online library that contains thousands of documents with millions of words**. Initially, the interviewer only asked me to search for single words, clarifying:

- Search for exact keywords ("overflow" returns true while "overflo" does not)
- Case-sensitivity can be ignored

My answer was to use a crawler algorithm that runs through each document and creates a lookup table that stores the information in which documents a given word is used, prior to any query executed. Then once a query is executed, all the algorithm have to do is to find the word in the lookup table and return the list of the documents that the word is used.

On the second step, they asked me what would I do if they wanted to search multiple words (not necessarily consecutive) and my answer was to make a new query for each word and find the intersection of the results.

Finally, the interviewer asked me what would I do if they wanted me to **query consecutive words or phrases** (eg. "stack overflow"). At this point, my lookup table failed since there are no connection between consecutive words and I couldn't come up with a solution in this approach. How can I handle these kind of queries? Are there any problems with my initial answers and design? I have searched on the Internet but couldn't find anything noteworthy.

Comment: Maybe building a Trie? If you read a word that is already marked as a valid word in the Trie, means it has been read before.

Comment: A trie wouldn't really help the storage of consecutive words (what I mean is phrases) and it doesn't work faster than a lookup map. It would work if they have asked me to do queries with completion, not exact words. Maybe I should change the description of the problem.

Comment: Add a response.

Answer (score 0):

For the second case, generate the map such that every key is a word and every value is a set of objects that have the following properties

```
{
  string document name : location/document_name,
  integer index : index, //location in document,
  toString : hash the object
}
```

Then when you need to find results for "stack overflow"

For all elements in set 1, does that value exist in set 2 but modified with the item_index + 1.

Get the results for two words but just return the doc names. If there are three words, do the same process you did for two words, but for the third word, check only the matches that passed word 1 and word 2 for word 2, and check to see if those items exist in set 3 with item_index + 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not sure if log N time complexity is tolerable in this case, considering the search operation wants immediate results. I mean in theory for a billion words, it only checks 9 elements which seem okay but still have some confusion around there. The real problem here is how to know these multiple words are in succession. The algorithm seems to work when searching for words in random locations in the document but I need a mechanism to ensure they are next to each other. Then again the lookup table does the same thing so no need to go for a tree solution.

Comment: When generating the array of documents also location of the word in an object of {document id, word location index in document}.                                                              this case when doing searches on 2 tokens for example, search first token 1, and token 2 and for every object in the array of objects for token 1, check if there is another object that has the same name, but index +1 in the other token result. You could optimize this by using yet another map, where the two token results will have maps with key (document), (locations).

Comment: As for getting this down to constant time, the only thing I can think about is using a map and I have no idea if it is even possible